# Desktop JSON Lines viewer?

Tags: json

Is there any decent Windows desktop `JSON lines (JSONL)` format viewer?

This format is also known as:

- Line-delimited JSON (LDJSON)
- newline-delimited JSON (NDJSON)

I'm looking for at least capability to extract properties from JSON objects and provide searching capabilities against properties. Ideally, smart highlighting and filtering capabilities.

Example:

```
{"some":"thing\n"}
{"may":{"include":"nested","objects":["and","arrays"]}}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), check

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

It's very useful

Comment: That looks very interesting and powerful! I've found a Sublime Text plug-in for `jq`  which looks promising. Will investigate `jq` syntax. Thanks!